# Option value doesn't match the right value

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a `$seasons` variable that contains 21 seasons. For each season I want to make a option in html that you can select. If I press the submit button I want the option that is selected before submitting, is still selected. I try to do that with this code:

```
<select name="season" id="season" class="filter-season">
          <option value="all">-- Alle seizoenen --</option>
          <?php foreach($seasons as $season): ?>
          <option <?php if (isset($_GET['season']) == $season['season']){?> selected = "true" <?php }; echo "selected" ?>\value="<?php echo $season['season'] ?>"><?php echo $season['season']; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

The problem is that the value of the option always jumps back to 21.

Answer (score 3):

You need

`selected="selected"`

instead of

`selected=true`

```
<select name="season" id="season" class="filter-season">
<option value="all">-- Alle seizoenen --</option>
<?php foreach($seasons as $season): ?>
<?php
$isSelected = (isset($_GET['season']) && $_GET['season'] == $season['season']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
?>
<option <?php echo $isSelected;?> value="<?php echo $season['season'] ?>"><?php echo $season['season'];?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `isset(...)` returns _boolean_

Comment: Diving into the code OP provided a bit more: **every** `option` element that's being generated will always have the `selected` attribute (`selected = "true"`). The `selected` attribute's mere presence is enough to set the `option` to the currently-selected element (its actual value is ignored). Thus, the last one added to the DOM will become the one that's selected by default, manifesting itself as the 21st selection in OPs case.

Comment: Now, you're allowing the `undefined index "season"` warning to be shown

Comment: Added isset() condition now.

Comment: Now it's good, but you forgot to close php tag before `<option`

Comment: @Styx, is everything fine now?

Comment: @Pupil Seems like it is :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your array type, but for a normal array:

```
 $seasons = [
     'winter',
     'summer'
 ];
 $selected_season = isset($_GET['season']) ? $_GET['season'] : false;


 <select name="season" id="season" class="filter-season">
     <option value="all">Alle seizoenen</option>
     <?php foreach($seasons as $season): ?>
         <option value="<?= $season; ?>" <?php $season == $selected_season ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>><?= $season; ?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake.
I've rewritten your code:

```
<select name="season" id="season" class="filter-season">
    <option value="all">-- Alle seizoenen --</option>
    <?php foreach($seasons as $season): ?>
        <option <?php if (isset($_GET['season']) &&  $_GET['season'] == $season['season']) echo "selected" ?> value="<?php echo $season['season'] ?>"><?php echo $season['season']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Your **"echo selected"** call was outside of your **if statement**. In your case you selected all the options and your browser then shows the last selected, in your case option 21. Also your **if statement** itself was wrong.

I've rewritten you're code. It now checks if `$_GET['season']` is set and if `$_GET['season']` equals `$season['season']`